# What is the simplest unique identifier available in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, guid, class-design

So I have this

```
public class Foo
{
    public int UniqueIdentifier;

    public Foo()
    {
        UniqueIdentifier = ????
    }    
}
```

How do I get a completely unique number?

Thanks!

Comment: lots more details needed: how unique do you want the number to be? how many ids will you need? can it be incremental (0,1,2,3...)? can it restart counting when the app is closed and reopened? will the ids be created and used in a single machine or can they be created remotely (communication between machines/processes)?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "completely unique number" unless you allow arbitrary (i.e. infinite) scale and precision...

Comment: Nonsense Marc. How about twelve? Twelve is certainly unique! There is only a single number called "twelve". don't believe me? Try to find another number that equals twelve but _is not twelve_. Can't do it, can ya? That's because twelve is _unique_.  :)

Comment: @Eric... not under modular arithmetic... 25 === 12 (mod 13)! :)

Comment: In the same sense of uniqueness as the randomness in http://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
System.Guid  guid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
String id = guid.ToString();
```

Comment: There are also some parameters you can pass to guid.ToString() to affect the sort of string you get back.

Answer (score 2):

Although not an int, a method of creating unique identifiers commonly uses GUIDs.  You can use Guid.NewGuid() to generate one.

There are some various conversion methods including byte arrays and strings.  For more information on GUIDs you can read up on them at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier).

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Guid` struct, like this.

```
public class Foo
{
    public readonly Guid UniqueIdentifier;

    public Foo()
    {
        UniqueIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();
    }    
}
```

Comment: HashCode is merely a hash for an object and is NOT always unique. Sometimes it's a mem address, sometimes it's other things. But point being, it's never guaranteed unique, even with a given CLR or Java VM.